# On opening google map second time, error is generating saying that You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the npm package **google-maps** [https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps].
and using angular material modal to show google map but whenever I open the map a second time an error generates saying:

`You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.`

[image]

I have tried removing the google maps APIs from the head of the HTML after the closing of the modal (in the ngOndestroy function), but it's not working.

Comment: This means that the Javascript library was loaded too many times. Please note that you should only include Maps Javascript API loading script once per page. Here you have the documentation about it:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview?_ga=2.178557028.1938357695.1632119960-1990201355.1602833828

Comment: Another thing is that you can be using third-party plugins. This means that multiple plugins are being used that implement the Google Maps Platform, and so the Maps JavaScript API requests also get imported multiple times. I would recommend checking which plugins are compatible with each other and checking the code of your webpages for any lingering <script> tags that you hardcoded before you started using the plugins.

Comment: @ElizabethEscoro I have tried removing the script before loading the map again but this isn't working.

Comment: Thanks, @ElizabethEscoro 
Calling the map load function again was creating the problem so, I created a static function at the root of the angular application. Now map load function is called only once when the application load and I fetch initialized map object on the opening of the modal instance.

Comment: @Master just write this as the answer to the question then

Answer (score 0):

Calling the map load function again was creating the problem so, I created a static function at the root of the angular application. Now map load function is called only once when the application load and I fetch initialized map object on the opening of the modal instance.

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer, please take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297066/meta-meta-stack-overflow-when-should-i-answer-or-comment. Please also look at see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. Or you can add it as an edit (under the heading Update etc) to your own question.